# TinyMCE custom button with popup

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm adding a button to my TinyMCE setup like this:

```
        setup : function(ed) {
        // Add a custom button
        ed.addButton('mybutton', {
            title : 'My button',
            image : 'mybutton.jpg',
            onclick : function() {
                // Add you own code to execute something on click
                ed.focus();
                ed.selection.setContent('Hello world!');
            }
        });
    },
```

I wan't to know if it's possible in the onclick event to open a popup and get some input from the popup. Which then can be pasted into the editor. Exactly like if you're doing a plugin i just want to create my own without all the plugin style and functions..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options:

**First** you can set or disable all css for the regular popup.

**Second** option is to open a classical popup or modal dialogue of your own using a button click or a click onto a specified element in the editor. When closing the popup you can write something back to the editor using a command like

```
tinyMCE.get("my_editor_id").execCommand("mceInsertContent",false,'whatever');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What if the popup contains a different page? How do I get the command into scope? Just like plugins work.. I assume your example wont work if it's getting executed on another page?

Comment: indeed, this won't work in case this other page is not on the same domain (for security reasons). it should work on the same domain if you use a modal window (see plugin inlinepopup)

Comment: glad to have been able to help