# tinyMCE modal popup as is for other use

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am trying to implement an extra button, to my tinyMCE editor. And as an example I took the source of localhost:61025/Web/Scripts/tinymce/themes/advanced/source_editor.htm, which is the reference of html(source) button.

[see the image](http://s18.postimage.org/q8irex83d/editor.png)

HOw can I creaet a button that will reference to my own file such as:

```
<input type=button value=html onclick="open_source_html()">
```

and the open_source_html() should open tinymcepopup of my:
localhost:61025/Web/Scripts/tinymce/themes/advanced/source_editor_CUSTOM.htm
file

Please help me.

Comment: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_toolbar_button.php

Comment: THank for comment, I found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328285/tinymce-custom-button-with-popup/6340798#6340798 , but it's not clear.

Comment: Alon, that links is helpfull, and  I used it to insert something into editor. But also I want a popup where I can put some other fields, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
            url : 'http://localhost/Save.html',
            width : 520,
            height : 340,
            resizable : "yes",
            inline : true,
            close_previous : "yes"

            });
```

Got it. Thanks Guys.

Comment: I found this from this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212705/cross-domain-tinymcepopup-result-of-expression-tinymce-undefined-is-not-an

Answer (score 2):

Alons link is a good one. You may also have a look at some of the plugins in the plugin directory of tinymce.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    ...
    setup : function(ed) {
        // Add a custom button
        ed.addButton('yourbutton', {
            title : 'Your button',
            image : 'img/example.gif', // path to your image
            onclick : function() {
                // Add you own code to execute something on click
                open_source_html();
            }
        });
    }
)};
```

Comment: thanks,THank for comment, I found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328285/tinymce-custom-button-with-popup/6340798#6340798 , but it's not clear.

Comment: that link is exactly what I want